# How to catch "data"-event while piping a download with mikeal request in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, request, pipe

I'm trying to react to the on.("data") event while using the mikeal request module in node js. I am piping the data into a writestream, which may complicate things. 
I'm using it like this:

```
var req = request(this.requestOptions(),function(err,resp,body){
    if(err){
        self.onFail.call(self.onFailContext);
    }
}).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(this.tempTarget));
req.on("data",function(chunk){console.log(chunk.length);});
```

The downloading works fine, but it seems the "data"-event is not called. When I dive into the source of request and put a console.log in the "data"-event I see it is called, so I think that means an event is being emitted. I just can't find a way to catch the event (and use the data to keep track of the download progress).

Comment: Does the response have a body? Data event is not emitted for headers.

Comment: Yes, it is a GET-request, and it successfully downloads files.